# K subset sum queries

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a list A of N integers and we are asked Q queries. Each query is denoted by an integer K, for which we need to return the sum of product of all possible sublists having exactly K elements.

We need to print the answers modulo 100003.

Example : Let N = 3 and array be {1,2,3} and let there are 2 queries.

Query 1 : K=1 then answer is 6 as For K=1 possible sublists are {1},{2},{3} so answer is 1+2+3=6.

Query 2 : K=2 then answer is 11 as For K=2 possible sublists are {1,2},{2,3},{3,1} so answer is (1×2)+(2×3)+(3×1)=2+6+3=11.

My Attempt :

```
#define MOD 100003
unsigned long long ans=0;
unsigned long long mulmod(unsigned long long a,unsigned long long b,unsigned long long c){
unsigned long long x = 0,y=a%c;
while(b > 0){
    if(b%2 == 1){
        x = (x+y)%c;
    }
    y = (y*2)%c;
    b /= 2;
}
return x%c;
}

void KSubset(unsigned long long *a,unsigned long long n,unsigned long long *s,unsigned long long sindex,unsigned long long index,unsigned long long k){

if (index>n)
    return;
if (k==0){
    unsigned long long productt = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<sindex;i++){
        productt=mulmod(productt,s[i],MOD);
    }
    ans=(ans%MOD + productt%MOD)%MOD;
    return ;
    }
s[sindex]=a[index];
KSubset(a,n,s,sindex+1,index+1,k-1);
KSubset(a,n,s,sindex,index+1,k);
}
```

But as queries can be upto N and N can be upto 3*10^4.So is there any better approach for this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hey...Noo..I want an algorithm.NOT CODE

Comment: As far I understood, you want to have your actual (I suppose working) code reviewed for possible improvements. I didn't accuse you asking for code. Just move your question to the site I mentioned :P ...

Comment: You can generate all sublists and do your sum. what is your problem ?

Comment: Does the array consist in increasing number from `1` to `N` ? or array values can be random number ?

Comment: FYI, this question is part of a live contest: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/infinitum-aug14/challenges/emma-and-sum-of-products It ends approximately at August 17th, 15:00 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Since {3, 1} is not a sublist, I'm going to assume that you meant subset. All calculations are to be done mod 100003; there is no problem, since everything here is algebraic. If you expand the factored polynomial

```
(1 + 1 x) (1 + 2 x) (1 + 3 x)
```

where each factor corresponds to an input value, then you get

```
1 + 6 x + 11 x^2 + 6 x^3,
```

and the answer to a query q is the coefficient of x^q. The naive algorithm is to equivalent to expanding a generalized [FOIL method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method), which takes exponential time. A better algorithm, with quadratic running time, is to accumulate the factors one by one, with a loop like

```
for (int i = degree; i > -1; i--) coefficient[i + 1] += coefficient[i] * x;
```

where `x` is the next value.

Comment: Oy, HackerRanked again. I'm following my usual policy: this answer has been up long enough that I'm leaving it. Problem setter, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have many queries so you can generate all subsets for your array,
then depending on k in the query you can choose (some subsets) .

ex: `a = {1, 2, 3}`

all subsets : `{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {}`

when you query with k = 1 (sum all subsets with size 1) ,
k = 2(apply your logic on subsets of size 2).

but if you may have 1 query only per array , maybe another algorithm will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(n * log^2 n) solution:

1)Write it as a polynomial (1 + x * a[0]) * (1 + x * a[1]) * ... * (1 + x * a[n - 1]). Now you need to expand it to get coefficients for each degree of x.

2)Instead of multiplying them naively, you can use divide and conquer approach: compute the product of the first half of terms and the second half(recursively). And now you can use Fourier fast transformer to multiply these two obtained polynomials quickly.

3)T(n) = 2 * T(n / 2) + n * log n = O(n * log^2 n).

Comment: How to use divide and conquer here?I didnt get you.Please explain

Comment: @user3923257 You want to multiply n term. You call a recursive multiply function for the first half and for the second one. Then you multiply product of the first half with the product of the second half with FFT.

Answer (score -1):

Using the STL, you may do:

```
std::size_t compute(const std::vector<int>& v, std::size_t k)
{
    std::vector<int> flags(v.size() - k, 0);
    flags.resize(v.size(), 1); // result in {0, .., 0, 1, .., 1} with k numbers 1

    std::size_t sum = 0;
    do {
        std::size_t mul = 1;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
            if (flags[i]) {
                mul *= v[i];
                mul %= 10003;
            }
        }
        sum += mul;
        sum %= 10003;
    } while (std::next_permutation(flags.begin(), flags.end()));
    return sum;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/ki9eAn)

Comment: N and the number of queries is like a few thousands and your code has exponential time complexity. It would work extremly long for let's say N=30000 and K=15000.

Comment: Additionally, it's nice to see a sentence or two describing at a high level what's going on (not my downvote).